# iOS Display Different Image on Click

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, ibaction

Using XCode, I am trying to figure out how to display a different image when someone clicks or presses down on one of my buttons before being taken to a second screen. For example, I have a contact icon on my home screen. When a user clicks the icon, it should change to a darker version on tap before going to the contact screen. Any help is appreciated.

```
-(IBAction) ButtonPressed :(id)sender
{
UIButton *tempButton = (UIButton *) sender;
int tag = tempButton.tag;
NSString *viewName;
switch (tag) 
{
    case 1:
        [FlurryAnalytics logEvent:@"Contact-Screen"];
        viewName = @"ContactScreen";
        if( self.appDelegate.sound)
            [Click play];
        [self.appDelegate moveToView:viewName];
        break;
}
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with XCode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, you just have to set a different image for the buttons selected state:

```
[myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mySelectedImage"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Or in interface builder:

[image]

Additional `UIControlState's` include:

```
enum {
   UIControlStateNormal               = 0,
   UIControlStateHighlighted          = 1 << 0,
   UIControlStateDisabled             = 1 << 1,
   UIControlStateSelected             = 1 << 2,
   UIControlStateApplication          = 0x00FF0000,
   UIControlStateReserved             = 0xFF000000
};
```

> The state of a control; a control can have more than one state at a
>   time. States are recognized differently depending on the control. For
>   example, a UIButton instance may be configured (using the
>   setImage:forState: method) to display one image when it is in its
>   normal state and a different image when it is highlighted.

Comment: This is great! I knew it had to be something that I was missing in Interface Builder -- great answer. One more question, if you don't mind: My buttons for screen to screen don't seem to display the selected image -- the screen switches too quickly for it to. Is there a way to make sure the selected or highlighted shows before switching to the next screen. It's not a priority, but it just creates a better user experience. Thank you, and have a great weekend.

Comment: Also, I'm relatively new to XCode, so anything in Interface Builder is easier than tweaking code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I've ever noticed in Xcode, whenever you decide to implement a customized button and don't specify a second image for use in the UIControlStateSelected state, Xcode automatically darkens the button for you when the user taps the buttons to show that they were, in fact, tapped.

Answer (score 0):

The 0x7f answer is almost correct (the correct state value is 'Highlighted' and not 'Selected'). For Swift users, it would be

```
myButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "myButtonImagePressed.png"), forState: .Highlighted)
```